# Pandas: How to sort dataframe rows by date of one column

Tags: python, pandas

So I have two different data-frame and I concatenated both. All columns are the same; however, the date column has all sorts of different dates in  the **M/D/YR** format.

[image]
*dataframe dates get shuffled around later in the sequence*

Is there a way to keep the whole dataframe itself and just sort ***the rows***  based on the dates in the date column. I also want to keep the format that date is in.

so basically

```
date        people
6/8/2015    1
7/10/2018   2
6/5/2015    0
```

gets converted into:

```
date          people
6/5/2015      0
6/8/2015      1
7/10/2018     2
```

Thank you!

*PS: I've tried the options in the other post on this but it does not work*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the 'date' column to pandas Datetime  and then sort

```
import pandas as pd
df= pd.DataFrame({'people':[1,1,1,2],'date': 
['4/12/1961','5/5/1961','7/21/1961','8/6/1961']})
df['date'] =pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df.sort_values(by='date')
```

Output:

```
date       people

1961-04-12  1

1961-05-05  1

1961-07-21  1

1961-08-06  2
```

To get back the initial format:

```
df['date']=df['date'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%y')
```

Output:

```
date    people
04/12/61    1

05/05/61    1

07/21/61    1

08/06/61    2
```

Comment: Thank you .I added one more line of code  to get the initial format and also printed the output

Answer (score 4):

Trying to elaborate on what can be done:
 Intialize/ Merge the dataframe and convert the column into datetime type

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'people':[1,2,0],'date': ['6/8/2015','7/10/2018','6/5/2015',]})
df.date=pd.to_datetime(df.date,format="%m/%d/%Y")
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   date      people
0   2015-06-08  1
1   2018-07-10  2
2   2015-06-05  0
```

Sort on the basis of date

```
df=df.sort_values('date')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    date    people
2   2015-06-05  0
0   2015-06-08  1
1   2018-07-10  2
```

Maintain the format again:

```
df['date']=df['date'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    date    people
2   06/05/2015  0
0   06/08/2015  1
1   07/10/2018  2
```

Comment: Since that winds up adding some leading '0's to the date, you could instead create a `dummy_date` column which is `datetime`, sort by that and then drop it to leave `date` truly untouched. But same basic idea :D

Answer (score -3):

why not simply?

```
dataset[SortBy["date"]]
```

can you provide what you tried or how is your structure?

In case you need to sort in reversed order do:

```
dataset[SortBy["date"]][Reverse]
```

Comment: What is `SortBy` ? Where is it defined? and `Reverse` ? How come this answer has 3 upvotes?